# What is the solution for JavaScript to add List element in the list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, function

The add function works on only the List given for the HTML. I need to give for the CSS & JavaScript List too.

```js
function add() {
  var newLi = document.createElement("LI");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inpuT").value;
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  newLi.appendChild(textnode);
  if (inputValue == '') {
    alert("Enter a value !");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(newLi);
  }
  document.getElementById("inpuT").value = "";
}
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

#tab1,
#tab2,
#tab3 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

input:checked+label {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.tabinfo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

#tab1:checked~#text1 {
  display: block;
}

#tab2:checked~#text2 {
  display: block;
}

#tab3:checked~#text3 {
  display: block;
}

header {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  cursor: default;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #b0ebef;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1"><text>HTML</text></label>
  <br>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2"><text>CSS</text></label>
  <br>
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3"><text>JavaScript</text></label>
  <div id="text1" class="tabinfo">
    <div>
      <h1>html</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inpuT"><a onclick="add()">Add</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li>Html</li>
      <li>List </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="text2" class="tabinfo">
    <div>
      <h1>css</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inpuT"><a onclick="add()">Add</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li>Css</li>
      <li>List</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="text3" class="tabinfo">
    <div>
      <h1>javascript</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inpuT"><a onclick="add()">Add</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>List</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When clicked on CSS / JavaScript, I'm unable to add the input text to the list instead it shows an alert box given.

This is the JavaScript code for which the alert box is showing. Is there a need to use for loop.

Comment: Hi, The issue is because you are having the same id for all the different lists. You need to update the id names and then on the basis of it, add the values to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code to make the id's for the input and list unique and then whenever the click happens use the unique id to add the input to the list.

```js
function add(list)
{
console.log(list)
var newLi = document.createElement("LI");
var inputValue = document.getElementById(`inpuT-${list}`).value;
var textnode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
newLi.appendChild(textnode);
if(inputValue == ''){
alert("Enter a value !");
}else{
document.getElementById(`myUL-${list}`).appendChild(newLi);
}
document.getElementById(`inpuT-${list}`).value = "";
}
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}
#tab1,#tab2,#tab3 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
input:checked + label {
 font-weight:700;
 font-size: 20px;
}  
.tabinfo {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #text1{
  display:block; 
}
#tab2:checked ~ #text2{
  display:block;
}
#tab3:checked ~ #text3{
  display:block;
}
header {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  cursor: default;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  background-color: #b0ebef;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo">
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label for="tab1"><text>HTML</text></label>
<br>
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab2"><text>CSS</text></label>
<br>
<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs"> 
<label for="tab3"><text>JavaScript</text></label>
<div id="text1" class="tabinfo">
    <div>
        <h1>html</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title html" id="inpuT-html" ><a onclick="add('html')">Add</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL-html">
        <li>Html</li>
        <li>List </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="text2" class="tabinfo">
    <div>
        <h1>css</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title css" id="inpuT-css" ><a onclick="add('css')">Add</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL-css">
        <li>Css</li>
        <li>List</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="text3" class="tabinfo">
    <div>
        <h1>javascript</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title js" id="inpuT-js" ><a onclick="add('js')">Add</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL-js">
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>List</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you've assigned the same id for all of your tags .you need to change them and later add them with onclick event

```
   <div class="todo">
    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
    <label for="tab1"><text>HTML</text></label>
    <be>
      <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
     <label for="tab2"><text>CSS</text></label>
   <be>
    <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab3"><text>JavaScript</text></label>
    <div id="text1" class="tabinfo">
    <div>
        <h1>html</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inputH" /><a onclick="add('inputH' 
   , 'myulH')">Add</a>
     </div>
     <ul id="myulH">
        <li>Html</li>
         <li>List </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="text2" class="tabinfo">
      <div>
        <h1>css</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inputC" ><a onclick="add('inputC' 
    , 'myulC')">Add</a>
      </div>
       <ul id="myulC">
        <li>Css</li>
        <li>List</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="text3" class="tabinfo">
      <div>
        <h1>javascript</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title....." id="inputJ" ><a onclick="add('inputJ' 
    , 'myulJ')">Add</a>
     </div>
     <ul id="myulJ">
         <li>JavaScript</li>
         <li>List</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
   </div>




function add(x , y)
{
  
var newLi = document.createElement("li");
var inputValue = document.getElementById(x).value;
var textnode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
newLi.appendChild(textnode);
if(inputValue == ''){
alert("Enter a value !");
}else{
document.getElementById(y).appendChild(newLi);
}
document.getElementById(x).value = "";
}
```